# RQ Worker throwing "ValueError"

Tags: python, redis

I'm attempting to get RQ/RQ-Worker running on my Flask application. I've tried to get it down to a very simple test case. Here's the general idea:

1. The user visits the `/test` page. Which triggers a job to be queued and returns the queued job's `job_key`
2. The worker (`worker.py`) processes the queued job.
3. The user can then visit the `/retrieve/<job_key>` page to retrieve the result. [This is not shown.]

The current job is just to add 2 + 2.

Here is the application code:

```python
from rq import Queue
from rq.job import Job

# import conn from worker.py
from worker import conn

app = Flask(__name__)

q = Queue(connection=conn)

def add():
  return 2+2

@app.route('/test')
def test():
  job = q.enqueue_call(func="add", args=None, result_ttl=5000)
  return job.get_id()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

The `worker.py` source code looks like this:

```python
from redis import StrictRedis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['default']
redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379'
conn = StrictRedis.from_url(redis_url)
if __name__ == "__main__":
  with Connection(conn):
    worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
    worker.work()
```

To my knowledge, the application code isn't the issue. I can visit the `/test` page which will enqueue the job. However, once I run the worker, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<>/dev/sched/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 588, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/home/<>/dev/sched/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 498, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/<>/dev/sched/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 206, in func
    return import_attribute(self.func_name)
  File "/home/<>/dev/sched/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 149, in import_attribute
    module_name, attribute = name.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I feel like the line:

```python
worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
```

is the problem just b/c of the nature of the error, but I have no idea how to fix it. Especially b/c [I've seen other projects](https://github.com/realpython/flask-by-example/blob/master/worker.py) that seem to use the exact same worker source code.

My technology stack is:

1. Flask (0.11.1)
2. Redis (2.10.5)
3. RQ (0.6.0)
4. RQ-Worker (0.0.1)

**EDIT**:

Beginning to think this is a bug. Check out this issue ticket in RQ's source: [issue #531](https://github.com/nvie/rq/pull/531).

Comment: Shouldn't `if name == "__main__":` be `__name__`

Comment: @Jonathan Yes. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was caused by RQ not being able to resolve my worker module.

The solution was to supply the "qualified" name to **enqueue**, e.g:

```
job = q.enqueue("app.worker.add", data)
```

Comment: you just don't know how you saved me. THANK YOU

Comment: I have same issue but this didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Having just faced this issue myself, but solutions like @Moby Duck's didn't work, I was able to narrow it down to a circular import error (`rq` doesn't report the error as a circular import error, but just the blanket `AttributeError` or something of the like).

If you suspect a circular import, or if @Moby Duck's style solution does not work, try:

- open a terminal in the working directory
- launch the python from the terminal (i.e., just `python` or `python3` in the terminal prompt)
- try to import the function from python running in the terminal (there, you should see an `ImportError` warning about a possible circular import, **if you do indeed have a circular import**)

Comment: If a circular import is the issue, that be identified by trying to execute the function synchronously before assigning it to the queue. This issue is most likely due to incorrect mapping of the working directory of RQ Worker.